# Reply tracking with PhpMailer and IMAP_SEARCH in PHP

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, imap

I am using PHPMailer to send the message and PHP imap_search to search the mails. My scenario is -

1. User sends an email from PHPMailer tp recipients. (DONE)
2. With the email user sends a custom message id say  (DONE)
3. Recipient replies the email.

Here, I need to search user's inbox for the reply. I need to search if user receives any reply on the email. I am not sure how can I do this.

I am using GMAIL SMTP for user to send the emails.

Thanks

Comment: If the user's email client cooperates AND your server supports the full IMAP query language, you should be able to do a HEADER search for In-Reply-To or References for your message-id.  If it doesn't, you can download all the headers using FETCH and look for them.  Alternatively, you can always put a unique token in the subject or the like.

Answer (score 0):

We found a workaround like this. To send the email in PHPMailer,we sent a unique ID with the email, assigning this into the custom header. (You can verify this message id, at recipient end in mail header).

```
$mid="<" . md5('MAXIFY'.(idate("U")-1000000000).uniqid()).'-sales@mydomain.com>';
$mail->MessageID = $mid;
$mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', $mid);
$mail->send();
```

Now to search the email, we used imap_search.

```
$date="25-May-2018";
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ON "'.$date.'"' );
foreach($emails as $email_number)
{
/* get information specific to this email */ 
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
print_r($overview);
}
```

Overview gives the details of message id etc. From here you can track if this is a reply or not. 
However, in few of the emails we found that message id is not present. So, we are adding a unique id in our email body and using our search criteria for imap_search is like -

```
$emails=imap_search($inbox,'TEXT "5b0b72417f673" ');
```

I did not find any other way to track the reply.